# Hibernate and Infinispan embedded compatibility

Tags: hibernate, infinispan

I'm trying to use Infinispan embedded as Hibernate 2LC provider.
Where can I find the correct version of `infinispan-embedded` dependency to integrate with `hibernate-infinispan`?

I tried Hibernate 4.3.x with different versions of `infinispan-embedded` dep (6, 7 and 8). I am getting some initialization errors. For example, whe I use `infinispan-embedded` `8.0.1.Final` I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unable to start region factory
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.(CacheImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.infinispan.commons.util.ServiceFinder.load(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Collection;
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.(ParserRegistry.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.createCacheManager(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:323)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: Actually you don have to specify the `infinispan-embedded` as explicit  dependency. You only have to add the `hibernate-infinispan` dep and it brings the `infinispan-core` as transitive deps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate 4.3.x is built against Infinispan 6.0.0.Final, see [libraries.gradle](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/4.3/libraries.gradle#L33). It's not built (or tested) against `infinispan-embedded`, if you do not use Maven, download artifacts `infinispan-core`, `infinispan-commons` - though, you might encounter further missing dependencies.